# Calculating CPU Performance in MIPS

Tags: performance, system

i was taking an exam earlier and i memorized the questions that i didnt know how to answer but somehow got it correct(since the online exam using electronic classrom(eclass) was done through the use of multiple choice.. The exam was coded so each of us was given random questions at random numbers and random answers on random choices, so yea)

anyways, back to my questions..

1.)
There is a CPU with a clock frequency of 1 GHz. When the instructions consist of two
types as shown in the table below, what is the performance in MIPS of the CPU?

```
           -Execution time(clocks)- Frequency of Appearance(%)
```

Instruction 1         10                     60
Instruction 2         15                     40

Answer: 125

2.)
There is a hard disk drive with specifications shown below. When a record of 15
Kbytes is processed, which of the following is the average access time in milliseconds?
Here, the record is stored in one track.
[Specifications]
Capacity: 25 Kbytes/track
Rotation speed: 2,400 revolutions/minute
Average seek time: 10 milliseconds

Answer: 37.5

3.)
Assume a magnetic disk has a rotational speed of 5,000 rpm, and an average seek time of 20 ms.  The recording capacity of one track on this disk is 15,000 bytes.  What is the average access time (in milliseconds) required in order to transfer one 4,000-byte block of data?

Answer: 29.2

4.)
When a color image is stored in video memory at a tonal resolution of 24 bits per pixel,
approximately how many megabytes (MB) are required to display the image on the
screen with a resolution of 1024 x768 pixels? Here, 1 MB is 106 bytes.

Answer:18.9

5.)
When a microprocessor works at a clock speed of 200 MHz and the average CPI
(“cycles per instruction” or “clocks per instruction”) is 4, how long does it take to
execute one instruction on average?

Answer: 20 nanoseconds

I dont expect someone to answer everything, although they are indeed already answered but i am just wondering and wanting to know how it arrived at those answers. Its not enough for me knowing the answer, ive tried solving it myself trial and error style to arrive at those numbers but it seems taking mins to hours so i need some professional help....

Comment: Question 2 is answer on this link.
http://getphilnitscertified.wordpress.com/tag/hard-disk/
Question 3 is the same type.
Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

### 1.)

n = 1/f = 1 / 1 GHz = 1 ns.

n*10 * 0.6 + n*15 * 0.4 = 12 ns (=average instruction time) = 83.3 MIPS.

### 2.)3.)

I don't get these, honestly.

### 4.)

> Here, 1 MB is 10^6 bytes.

3 Bytes * 1024 * 768 = 2359296 Bytes = 2.36 MB

But often these 24 bits are packed into 32 bits b/c of the memory layout (word width), so often it will be 4 Bytes*1024*768 = 3145728 Bytes = 3.15 MB.

### 5)

CPI / f = 4 / 200 MHz = 20 ns.

Comment: On 4.: you can safely assume this is a notational issue, meant to be: "1 MB = 10^6 bytes".

Comment: Thanks for the help, some of those did not match the correct answers i have stated above, although number 5 did. Oh well.. ill look at this some other time.. ill wait for more answers. :) Thanks again!